# Strange Results from Biquad Peaking EQ Filter

Tags: filters, sampling, equalization, equalizer

I have a signal that I am filtering on an MCU (STM32F405) that I get from a codec (CS42L52).  It is being sampled at a sampling frequency of 48kHz (actually between 48400 and 48600).  I have a ping pong buffer setup with DMA and am using I2S to send the signal between the MCU and codec.

I seem to have a glitch somewhere when filtering.  It is somehow related to the buffer size, it happens at (buffer_size / 4) samples, but only when I am filtering.  Below is a picture of both channels of my output, the top signal is the left channel unfiltered and the bottom is the right channel filtered.

[image: filtered signal]

I can switch the channel that is filtered and have the same results on the opposite channel.  It is a fixed point filter with coefficients in Q29 format and look like

```
531850828 (b0), -952252845 (b1), 507513243 (b2), 952252845 (a1), -502493159 (a2)
```

for a center frequency of 3150Hz, Q of 7.2, Gain of -3, and sampling frequency of 48kHz. My filter uses the equation

```
y = b0 * x[n] + b1 * x[n-1] + b2 * x[n-2] + a1 * y[n-1] + a2 * y[n-2]
```

I am able to process all of the data in my buffer in less than 5ms depending on buffer size.

While the glitch appears at all frequencies, it tends to be most prominent around the frequency that I am filtering.  Does this mean my coefficients are somehow incorrect?

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

### Edit:

I am using the CMSIS library from ARM to do my filtering. I have followed this [example](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/arm_graphic_equalizer_example_q31_8c-example.html) from the CMSIS documentation.  According to the documentation, I need to scale my coefficients to be between [-1, +1) which is why I use Q29 format, and then shift them by 2. There is a postshift parameter coded into the Q31 filter.
[Here](http://pastebin.com/HfJxsEre) is the CMSIS code for the filter.

From the codec I get 24-bits of data which I pass through the filter and then send back to the codec.  The accumulator is 64 bit and the code is in C.  I guess I have made an assumption that 24-bits is small enough to not have overflow from the filter, but I am new to signal processing.  How do I correct for overflow?

### Edit 2

I have been playing with the coefficients and when I set the gain to 0, the signal comes out clean.  If I leave all the parameters except gain the same and change the gain (I tried +1.0 and -1.0), then I have distorted output.  This is making me think more and more that it is arithmetic overflow. I tried multiplying the input of the filter by 0.125 to scale it down by 1/8, but that did not seem to help. What is the proper way to deal with this?

### Edit 3

Using the code RBJ provided, I get the same sort of output as before. This time I have converted the input into floating point format and then back to q31 for output.  If I change the coefficients to have a 0 gain, I get a clean output, but as soon as I change the gain to anything but 0, it creates noise.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/39ZPo.png]

In my code, I am filtering one value at a time through filterBuffer.  When I receive the data from DMA, I have to rotate the data right by 16 places to correct
for the DMA's FIFO packing the data in the wrong order. For example, when the codec sends 24-bits 0xABCD EF00, the DMA will pack it as 0xEF00 ABCD. This is fixed by using the asm ror #16 instruction.

---

```
// f0 = 3150, Q = 4.3, Gain = 3.0, Fs = 48000
sectionData *coeffs = malloc(sizeof(sectionData));
coeffs->filterCoefficients[0] = 1.0155644882603565; // b0
coeffs->filterCoefficients[1] = -1.7632428285856931; // b1
coeffs->filterCoefficients[2] = 0.90897819415372805; // b2
coeffs->filterCoefficients[3] = 1.7632428285856931; // -a1
coeffs->filterCoefficients[4] = -0.92454268241408455; // -a2

static float32_t states[4] = {0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}

/* loop in main after receiving data in rxbuf */
for (i = 0; i < BUFFERSIZE; i++) {
    *ptrIn = *rxbuf++;
    asm("mov %[result], %[value], ror #16" : [result] "=r" (*ptrIn) : [value] "r" (*ptrIn));

    fIn = (float32_t) *ptrIn / 2147483648u;
    filterBuffer(1, 1, &fIn, &fOut, &states[0], &coeffs);
    filtered[i] = fOut * 2147483648u;

    asm("mov %[result], %[value], ror #16" : [result] "=r" (*filtered[i]) : [value] "r" (filtered[i]));
    asm("mov %[result], %[value], ror #16" : [result] "=r" (*ptrIn) : [value] "r" (*ptrIn));

    // separate left and right channel, only filter left channel.    
    if (i%2 == 0)
        *txbuf++ = (uint32_t)filtered[i];
    else
        *txbuf++ = *ptrIn++;
}
```

Comment: how, exactly, are you doing your fixed-point arithmetic?  by *"Q29"*, do you mean that there are 3 bits left of the binary point?  and how are you calculating coefficients.  it appears to me that you got the sign of $a_2$ correct (if you're adding in the difference equation).  but since your coefficients are fixed point, somewhere in your code, you have to be shifting right by 29 bits.  is your accumulator 64 bits?  are you doing this in C?  are you using *long* and *long long* types or explicit *int32* and *int64*?  you probably have an arithmetic overflow and you don't know it yet.

Comment: consider posting a snippet of code.

Comment: also, if you're coding this equation explicitly > **y = b0 * x[n] + b1 * x[n-1] + b2 * x[n-2] + a1 * y[n-1] + a2 * y[n-2]** then you will have circular address wrap-around issues similarly to when folks encode an FIR filter or long delay line.  *"While the glitch appears at all frequencies, it tends to be most prominent around the frequency that I am filtering."* -- i'll bet it's arithmetic overflow in your fixed-point registers.  you might need to go to Q4.28 or Q5.27 or Q6.26 .  you have plenty of bits to the right, may as well pad a couple more on the left.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am using your equations to calculate the coefficients from [here](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt). And then changing the sign of the 'a' coefficients to fit my filter equation. In order to put them in to Q29 format, I am taking the floating point value I get from your equations and then multiplying them by 2^29, then truncating them as integers. I edited the post to answer your other questions.

Comment: It looks like the state of your filter is reset at the beginning of every block. Are you sure it is persistent? Check the scope of all variables which might store the state of the filter.

Comment: @pichenettes, he seems to store the states at the bottom and loads them at the top.  but the code could surely be simpler.  one unanswered question is what is the value of `S->postShift` (which determines the value of `uShift` and `lShift`)?  Rick, i could write that loop a lot simpler.  i dunno why Rick has to process two samples at a time in the loop, i don't see how it pipelines better, but i dunno this particular ARM.  also you should realize that the output states `Yn1, Yn2` of `stage` are the same as the input states `Xn1, Xn2` of `stage+1` (this appears to be cascaded DF1).

Comment: I currently have everything in the main loop of the program with static state variables.  The filter being reset is a good suggestion, but I am pretty sure the variables are not being reset.  If it was being reset, wouldn't it align with my buffer size instead of buffer size / 4 ?

Comment: My postShift value is 2 for the Q29 coefficients.  And you are right, it is a cascaded DF1, but I only use one stage. Should I be using more than one stage?

Comment: *"Should I be using more than one stage?"* no, but your code was structured as such and i didn't know what the value of `S->numStages` is.  why are you doing this:`acc_l = acc & 0xffffffff;
      acc_h = (acc >> 32) & 0xffffffff;
      Yn1 = (uint32_t) acc_l >> lShift | acc_h << uShift;`  ?  why not just `Yn1 = (q31_t) (acc >> lShift);`
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick, just because i'm lazy, i don't wanna rewrite your code, but i'm pasting a snippet of old code of mine that does cascaded biquad filtering.  it's in single-precision float, but could be modified to be Q3.29 (or i would recommend Q4.28) with use of the `q64_t` and `q32_t` types and a little right shifting.  it swaps the nesting of the sections and the block of samples, it does the sections (or "stages") on the inside loop and reuses those states as i have described.  but your nesting (with the section loop on the outside) might be better (faster).

just an idea about how to structure the code.  otherwise, it's gonna be about how to do the fixed-point arithmetic, and i surely don't see why you're doing this bit-field manipulation.  just shift the 64-bit acc to the right by 28 or 29 bits (depending on your scaling factor).

`typedef struct
    {
    float filterCoefficients[5];    /* b0, b1, b2, a1, a2   (a0 is normalized to 1) */
    } sectionData;`

`int filterBuffer(long Nsamples, int Nsections, float *input, float *output, float *filterStates, sectionData **sections)   {
    register long n;
    register int i;
    register sectionData **section_ptr;
    register float sampleValue, state1, state2, *state_ptr, *coef_ptr;`

```
for (n=0; n<Nsamples; n++)
    {
    section_ptr = sections;                         /* reset section pointer */
    state_ptr = filterStates;                       /* reset state pointer */

    sampleValue = input[n];                         /* get input sample */

        state2 = *state_ptr++;                      /*   x[n-2]            */
        state1 = *state_ptr--;                      /*   x[n-1]            */
        *state_ptr++ = state1;                      /*   x[n-1] -> x[n-2]  */
        *state_ptr++ = sampleValue;                 /*   x[n]   -> x[n-1]  */

    i = Nsections;
    while (--i >= 0)
        {
        coef_ptr = &((*section_ptr++)->filterCoefficients[0]);  /* point to section filter coefficients */

        sampleValue =  *coef_ptr++ * sampleValue;   /*   b0*x[n]           */
        sampleValue += *coef_ptr++ * state1;        /*   b1*x[n-1]         */
        sampleValue += *coef_ptr++ * state2;        /*   b2*x[n-2]         */

        state2 = *state_ptr++;                      /*   y[n-2]            */
        state1 = *state_ptr--;                      /*   y[n-1]            */
        *state_ptr++ = state1;                      /*   y[n-1] -> y[n-2]  */

        sampleValue += *coef_ptr++ * state1;        /*  -a1*y[n-1]         */
        sampleValue += *coef_ptr++ * state2;        /*  -a2*y[n-2]         */

        *state_ptr++ = sampleValue;                 /*   y[n]   -> y[n-1]  */`
```

`/*
 *     at this point sampleValue is the output of the section just completed 
 *     and will be the input to the section about to be computed unless this 
 *     is the last section, in which case sampleValue is the input.
 *     state1 and state2 are the output states of the section just completed
 *     and will be the input states of of the section about to be computed.
 */`
            }

```
    output[n] = sampleValue;                        /* store output sample */
    }

return 0;
}`
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to do this! Unfortunately, I am still having the same problem.  I have updated the post with "Edit 3" with the details, and added the code that I am using to call the filter.

Comment: well, i dunno what the problem is.  at first it looked like it was synchronized with the sinusoid so i thought it was distortion due to wrap-around overflow somewhere.  shouldn't happen with `float` and it doesn't appear synchronous with the waveform.  do you know the number of samples spacing between the glitches?  maybe it has to do with your input buffer or how you're moving your samples in and out.

Comment: @Rick, can you modify your program so that it's just a "wire" (so that the output samples are a copy of the input samples) and see if this glitch ends up in the output?

Comment: In my original code, the glitch seemed to happen every (buffer_size / 4) samples, but it does not seem to be the same using your code. I have generated a sampled sine wave and placed it in my code in order to test the filter and not use the input from the codec and there are no glitches in the output, everything sounds clean.  I have also noticed that if I try to boost or cut the input from the codec, there is no change in amplitude, but there is when I am filtering generated signal.

Comment: I have also commented out the call to the filter in my code and run everything as is -- input going to ouput--  and the output is clean.  No glitches whatsoever. Could this be a sample rate problem?  I measure my sample rate at around 48500 Hz, when I'd really like it at 48000.

Comment: and i still dunno why you do this:      `acc_l = acc & 0xffffffff;      acc_h = (acc >> 32) & 0xffffffff;
      Yn2 = (uint32_t) acc_l >> lShift | acc_h << uShift;` instead of just this: `Yn2 = (q31_t) (acc >> lShift);`  why are you doing this bit shuffling?

Comment: well, i don't get it. i am suspicious that it's something to do with your buffering. especially if you seemed to measure the glitch spaced by something related to buffer_size (but buffer_size/4 seems curious). if it was synchronized to the sinusoid itself, it's a problem with the filter, likely an arithmetic overflow somewhere (which can happen with fixed-point if you're not careful with enough guard bits on the left, which is why i would suggest Q4.28 or Q5.27 rather than Q3.29) . i just dunno.

Comment: I'm not sure why the code is written that way either, it is from the CMSIS library written by ARM. I don't get it either, but thanks for looking at it.  I'll post back here when I figure it out.

Comment: i mean, `lshift` must be, in your case, 29.  your coefficients are scaled up by $2^{29}$ and cast to integer values.  then when you do integer multiplication with those scaled-up coefficients, the result in `acc` is $2^{29}$ times too large.  so you divide by $2^{29}$ by shifting it right by 29 bits.  no big wop.  (for now, don't worry about rounding, but it's easy to do.)

Comment: Alright, I have completely removed the noise. It was definitely because of my buffer. For some reason in my loop, if I divide my BUFFERSIZE by 2, it works fine.

Comment: okay @Rick , perhaps your buffer was extending into someone else's memory block and your samples got trampled on.

Comment: look into my suggestion about the fixed-point arithmetic.  it's easier than your code makes it out to be.  and you probably still need more bits to the left of the binary point than just 3.

Comment: I'll look into it.  Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: just remember that your fixed-point coefficients are $2^f$ times bigger than their intended values (where we have Q$i.f$ where $i+f=32$ or whatever your word width is). make sure your accumulator is double the width and make sure, using C, that there is the proper "promotion" of the type.  perhaps make your coefficients into `q63_t` to start with.  then you **know** your product and accumulator will be 64 bits when you're done.  then when all the terms are added up, shift the result right by 27 or 28 or 29 bits and you have your result.  there are issues about rounding we can talk about later.